# How to install libatomic along with devtoolset11

Tags: gcc, centos7

I ran into the following link issue

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: cannot find -latomic
```

I came across this [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1809598) that says this problem happens when `gcc-toolset-9-libatomic-devel` is not installed. I was wondering if there is a way to install `libatomic` for CentOS7 along with `devtoolset-11`. Apparently, `yum install devtoolset-11-libatomic` does not exist.

How could I get `devtoolset` install `libatomic`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yum install devtoolset-11-libatomic-devel
```